# Ffmpeg Webm Encoding Error

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert various video file formats into .webm using ffmpeg v. 0.6.1 but am having a few troubles. It creates the file but is zero kb in size. I also get the following error:

```
Encoder (codec id 146) not found for output stream #0.0
```

I have tried loads of fixes but none seem to work. I have used  --enable-libvorbis on ./confure and downloaded the latest version of libvpx and all the other dependencies listed here: http://www.videochat-scripts.com/install-ffmpeg-mplayer-flvtool2-yamdi-x264-theora-mp3lame-vorbis-ogg-faac/

Are there any patches I need to apply from webm? Or is this version of ffmpeg meant to support it?

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. The error was caused by a dodgy install of ffmpeg. Reinstalled and it works fine.

Comment: What was wrong with this answer? Voted undelete.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac users having the issue, [this guy](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/198) pointed out that you need to change the syntax slightly to include a codec in *ffmpeg* when installing with *homebrew*.

Example:

`brew install ffmpeg --with-libvpx --with-theora --with-libogg --with-libvorbis`

Answer (score 3):

You need --enable-libvpx on your ./configure, e.g.:

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab
```

Comment: I have solved it now but this may have worked instead of having to reinstall.Thank you!